# Truncating actual values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a sheet with various columns and i use it to upload data to Sql server.
The data type in SQLServer is Decimal(4,1). I used this vba code:

**Data:**

**STATION**
439.26978545

**Code**

```
ActiveSheet.Range("I:I").NumberFormat = "#00.0"
```

It only changed the data I see in the sheet and my query errors out because the data type does not match because it is still sending 439.26978545.

Is there any way to run a code like above that would fix the entire column to Decimal(4,1)?

Comment: You can loop through the column and round to the first decimal place.

Comment: Excel is always going to store the full value of the number, regardless of the **display** formatting. If you want to truncate the value itself you'll either have to change the number value (e.g. convert 439.26978545 to 439.30000000) or reformat the cell as a text value with the formatting you want and expect the SQL ingestion to convert from text to a number.

Comment: After setting the .NumberFormat you can use `ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True` but make sure you know what yo are about to do before jumping in and doing it. You will permanently lose all precision in the entire workbook, not just the column you want to truncate.

Comment: `[I:I] = [INDEX(IF((I:I<>"")*(ISNUMBER(I:I)),ROUND(I:I,1),IF(I:I = "","",I:I)),)]`

Comment: 1. If you are running a query, why can't you round the field in the WHERE statement? 2. If exporting to CSV (and possibly direct to SQL, I don't have time to check), you get the number-as-displayed, not the raw value.

Comment: @ScottCraner that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Scott Craner gave the right answer to this questions. Since he did not post his answer (if he does, I will select that) and I really don't like unanswered questions. I am posting it here so that it may help ppl:

```
[I:I] = [INDEX(IF((I:I<>"")*(ISNUMBER(I:I)),ROUND(I:I,1),IF(I:I = "","",I:I)),)]
```